# Teamspeak hotkey needs to be reconfigured after ts3overlay update

Tags: teamspeak

Whenever I start Teamspeak I see this error message, which stops the software from loading until I press the 'OK' button. This sucks. How to fix it?

[image: Teamspeak 'hotkey needs to be reconfigured' error]

> Due to the latest ts3overlay update, your hotkey needs to be reconfigured.
>
> Please open the ts3overlay plugin configuration page and set your hotkey in the "Input" tab.

Comment: Move this question to Superuser perhaps? http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop the message interrupting Teamspeak loading *every single time*:

Settings / Plugins / Teamspeak 3 Overlay plugin / Settings / Input

Then enter a random hotkey.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the separate plugin recently, your TS3 Client might be seriously outdated.

Be aware that the TS3 Overlay plugin is included in the latest TS3 Client, so the best thing you can do is uninstall the current client in `Start`, `Control Panel`, 'Programs', and [download](http://ts3overlay.r-dev.de/download) and install the latest TS3 Client.